# linear transformation of a subset with inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, functional-inequalities

**Let $F$ be the vector space of all functions $R \to R$.
Let $U_2$ be the subset of F formed by all functions bounded by above (a function $f: R \to R$ is bounded from above if there exists $M ∈ R$ such that $$
f(x) ≤ M, \ \ \text{for all} \ x ∈ R.
$$ Show that $U_2$ is not a subspace of $F$.**
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySU8r.png)

I am confused with the process to check if $U_2$ is not closed under scalar multification.

Here is what I did.
Take any $u ∈ U_2$, any scalar $c ∈ R$
$c*f(x) ≤ c*M$; for all $x \in R$

When c < 0,
$$c*f(x) ≥ c*M$$
I thought when $c < 0$, $f$ is not in $U_2$ because $c*f(x) ≥ c*M$ is not the form of $f(x) ≤ M$.

Let's consider when $f(x) = -x^2$, then f(x) ≤ 0 and -f(x) ≥ 0.
However, **"The fact that $-f(x) = x^2 ≥ 0$ doesn't mean that $-f$ is not in $U_2$"**

This is what I got as my feedback.

**"The function $f(x) = -x^2$ is in $U_2$ because it is bounded above : there exists a real number $M$ (here $M=0$ works) such that for all $x$, $f(x) ≤ M.$ But you can't find any $M'$ such that $-f(x) ≤ M'$ for all x, so $-f$ is not in $U_2$."**

This is the solution from my prof.
Don't I need to change that inequality sign when I use a scalar?

**"This is not because $-f(x) >= -M$ that $-f$ is not in $U_2$. The constant function $f(x)=1$ is in $U_2$, and  $-f(x)=-1$ is again in $U_2$."**
According to this, constant $f(x)$ always works under the condition. Then how am I supposed to prove some $f(x)$ doesn't work. I would like to make this generalized without some specific example.

Do I need to find an example all the time?

Please give me some insight on this question. I am dying to understand this.

Thank you!

Comment: The solution provided by your professor is fine. I would of provided a similar one. What's about it that you disagree with or that you don't understand?

Comment: Pleas learn the basics of Latex. I have attempted to remedy to a certain number of things...

Comment: Hello. Here is a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/15078#15078) tutorial for the equations

Comment: @Sgg8 Thank you so much!

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you! I am sorry. This is my first time posting a question. I will look latex up!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Is it possible to make this in a general form? I would like to see this solution as -f(x)≥-M, but my prof is saying "This is not because -f(x) >= -M that -f is not in U2. The constant function f(x)=1 is in U2, and -f(x)=-1 is again in U2.". I understand that he gave some actual example f(x) which is -x^2, and I think for -f(x) ≤ M'. there is not M' in R because -f(x) goes to +inf. Right?

Comment: Well, yes, there is a general form. Let $f$ be any function with an upper bound but with no lower bound and take $\lambda<0$. Then $f\in U_2$, but $\lambda f\notin U_2$. Now, would you mind explaining why you want a general form?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How can I show $λf$
 is not working when $λ<0$
? The reason I want a general form is because I don't think I always can think of an actual example. If I prove this in a general form, I think it should be good enough because this should work for x and M in R

Comment: If $\lambda<0$ and $f$ has no lower bound, then $\lambda f$ has no upper bound, and therefore $\lambda f\notin U_2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can I understand what's going on here as follows? if $λ<0$ and $f$ has only upper bound such as $f \leq M$, then $λf \geq λ*M$ (has no uppder bound), and therefore $λf ∉ U_2$

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos if $\lambda < 0$ and $f$ has no lower bound (but with some upper bound), then $\lambda*f$ is reflected about the x-axis because $\lambda < 0$. Doesn't it mean the upper bound of $f$ becomes a lower bound of $\lambda*f$?

Comment: No, it does not. If $f(x)=2-x^2$, then the number $2$ is an upper bound of $f$. However, $-2$ is not a lower bound of $(-2)\times f$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos When it comes to scalar mutliplication with some bound, Am I supposed to just leave the bound as it is? How am I supposed to show when $λ < 0$, $λf$ has no upper bound while $f$ has lower bound?

Comment: If $f$ has no lower bound and $\lambda<0$, then $\lambda f$ has no upper bound, because, if it had an upper bound $M$, then, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $f(x)>\frac M\lambda$ (since $\lambda f(x)<M$).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This makes sense! Thanks a lot!!!